# Redirection to a controller in sub folder

Tags: codeigniter

I cant access to my login controller which is located in the sub directory login.
it is working perfectly in my local server.

in my default controller I did this

```
public function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('url');

}

public function index()
{
    redirect("login");
}
```

And in my routes.php

```
$route['login'] = 'login/log';
```

Can anyone help me out please?

Comment: what is your base url in config

Comment: http://signatureind.com/demo/crm/

Comment: what is your site_url error is in that part

Comment: Put forward slash at the end of the base path. Read in description how to make it just above line where `$config['base_url']` is set.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
IN YOU CONFIG.PHP

$config['base_url'] = '';

$config['index_page'] = '';

$config['uri_protocol'] = 'REQUEST_URI';
```